# iOS app Upload Photo to Facebook and Server approach

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

When the user takes a pic on the iOS app, the following would have to be done (in no particular order):

- The photo has to be uploaded to our server.
- The photo has to be posted on to Facebook

What is the best approach to do this ?

**Scenario 1:**

1. iOS app uploads the photo to our server
2. iOS app uploads photo to the Facebook

**Scenario 2:**

1. iOS app uploads the photo to the server
2. Our server uploads the photo to Facebook

**Questions:**

1. Which approach is better (scenario 1 or scenario 2 or is there any other better approach)  ?
2. Which approach is followed by other apps which do stuff like this. (apps like Instagram / Foodspotting ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you are asking and the information you are providing (I don't know if there are other requirements), I would probably go for Scenario 2 for the following reasons:

**The User Comes First**: In this case, I am thinking about data leaving the user's device. Most people have a limited data plan, which means, you should try to use the least amount of resources possible (in this case, data & their attention span).

**You have more flexibility:** You can retry the upload to facebook in case of an error without disturbing the user. For example, if for any reason, you could not upload to Facebook on the first try, then you can retry without holding the user's attention hostage.

**You have more control/measurements:** Here I am assuming certain functionality about your app. But let's say you allow people to upload files to your server, but they can choose if they post to Facebook, then you can start seeing what percentage of your users actually post to Facebook, and start to see patterns about your users. This kind of information is always valuable.